# link within a list which is already a set of links

Tags: html, css, html-lists

how to do like when I hover a list item (li), there will be the second link which is click-able to perform other action?

example :

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @PavloMykhalov yes

<ul>

<li><a href="#">personal</a></li>
<li><a href="#">work</a></li>
<li><a href="#">family</a></li>

</ul>

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far on that list? It will be very simple to use 2 links inside a <li>

Comment: @Caelea but how to align them horizontally?

Comment: @AnaisRichmond well, you need to learn some CSS here. There are at least 3 options: a) display:inline-block on links b) using floats on links c) display:table-cell on links and table-row on <li> and table on <ul>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what you are searching for:

The HTML Code:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#list-link-1"><span class="name">List 1</span></a><a href="#edit-link-1"><span class="edit">edit</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#list-link-2"><span class="name">List 2</span></a><a href="#edit-link-2"><span class="edit">edit</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#list-link-3"><span class="name">List 3</span></a><a href="#edit-link-3"><span class="edit">edit</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS is:

```
ul {
    list-style:none;
}
li {
    width:286px;
    background-color:lightgray;
    margin:5px;
    height:58px;
    font-size:20px;
}
li:hover {
    background-color:#bbbbbb;
}
a {
    text-decoration:none;
    width:250px;
    color:#333333;
}
span {
    position:absolute;
}
.name {
    border:3px solid lightgray;
    padding:15px;
    z-index:1;
    width:250px;
    height:22px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.name:hover {
    border:3px solid gray;
}
.edit {
    padding:7px 15px;
    margin:10px 0px 10px 200px;
    z-index:5;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.edit:hover {
background-color:gray;
border-radius:15px;
}
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/8qyr4/

Answer (score 1):

This is a very crude example of how to do it, may be lots of other ways, just take a look.

**HTML**:

```
<ul> 
    <li>
        <a href="#">personal</a>
        <a href="#" class="show">show</a>
    </li> 
    <li>
        <a href="#">personal</a>
        <a href="#" class="show">show</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**:

```
  ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
ul li {
    background: #999;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 300px;
}
ul li a {
    margin: 10px 0px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.show {
    display: none;
    float: right;
}
ul li:hover .show {
    display: inline-block
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qzJL6/

Answer (score 0):

Given this HTML code:

```
<li>
  <a href="#">Personal</a> <a href="#" class="second-link">edit</a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#">Work</a> <a href="#" class="second-link">edit</a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#">Family</a> <a href="#" class="second-link">edit</a>
</li>
```

You can add the following CSS rules:

```
.second-link {
  display: none;
}

li:hover .second-link {
  display: block;
}
```

When pointer is hover `LI`, relative `a.second-link` will be shown.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you are looking at

http://jsfiddle.net/cancerian73/59d9H/

CSS

```
#wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#wrapper ul {
    list-style: none;
    max-width: 200px;
}
#wrapper ul li {
    display: block;
    font: bold 14px/22px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #333;
    background-color: #ccc;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
    position: relative;
}
#wrapper ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
#wrapper ul li a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.edit {
    position: absolute;
    right: 2px;
    top: 2px;
}
```